# Why should a 2x2 zero matrix be created using numpy.zeros((2,2)) and not numpy.zeros(2,2)?

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

From what I read online I have understood that it is because it is a tuple, but the definition of tuple as just a collection of objects does not make sense in this context. Have I come across the wrong reason? If not, could someone elaborate on this with an example?

I am using numpy.

```
w = numpy.zeros((2,2))
```

The error message I get when using single set of parentheses is:
 "TypeError: data type not understood."

Comment: Because the tuple is interpreted as a single positional argument. Without the extra parentheses, you're supplying two separate arguments.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html#numpy-zeros The error message is not just a generic message saying the shape wasnt understood, its specifically saying you passed `dtype = 2` which could not be interpreted.

Comment: In Python, positional arguments can be `foo(args)` or `foo(*args)`.  In first case `args` has to be a single object, such as a list or tuple (`foo((1,2))`.  In the second, the input can be multiple items. as in `foo(1,2)` or `foo(*(1,2))`.  Some times the function is written it accepts one type or other, sometimes it accepts either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `numpy` documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html):

> numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=float, order='C')

The first argument is the shape of the matrix with the datatype as the second. When you input with only one set of parentheses, it takes the shape to be `2` and the dtype to also be `2`, that's why it's complaining about not recognizing a datatype (because `2` is not a datatype).

Comment: I don't get it, why does using 2 parentheses solve the problem? What if the datatype that it defaults to in that case? Why does it not do so when using single set of parentheses?

Comment: When you use two sets of parentheses, the first argument, `shape`, becomes a tuple of `(2, 2)` while the second argument, `dtype`, uses the default value of `float`. When only using one set of parentheses, the interpreter doesn't know that both the `2`'s are for the `shape` argument, so it passes the second `2` to `dtype.